# Flutter Android Manifest unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest><application><activity>

Tags: android, xml, flutter, dart, android-manifest

I added Facebook code to my `AndroidManifest.xml` and now when launching my emulator I get this exception:

`C:\Users\...\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:17:7-181: AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest><application><activity>.`

Shorter exception version:

`AAPT: error: unexpected element <activity> found in <manifest><application><activity>.`

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" />
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

I tried looking for a similar problem but failed to find a solution.
Kindly explain why is this resulting in an exception and what is the solution?

Comment: can you share your all manifest file codes?

Comment: @malibayram91 Thank you very much for your quick answer, I just realized that I embedded it in the wrong place rather than directly under ```<application ... ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I misplaced the Facebook code and embedded it inside of

`<activity android:name=".MainActivity" ...`

While I was supposed to embed it directly under

`<application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" ...`